# Changing the order of properties when controls are added to a WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, default

When adding new controls to a WPF Window (or other "custom" control), such as a label, the IDE prebuilds such as

```
<Label Content="Label" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="6" Grid.RowSpan="2" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="54,11,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

I would like it to change the default order and formatting, such as...

```
<Label Name="label1" 
       Content="Label" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       VerticalAlignment="Top"
       Grid.Row="?" 
       Grid.Column ="?" 
       Height="28"/>
```

Especially as a newbie to WPF, I hate how things are just "thrown" together by the IDE.  I like to have the name of controls up front, primary alignment issues, then the where and extras regarding the control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Don't know the way of stablish a default order in the properties, but maybe Xaml Markup Styler can be of your interest. It's a plugin for VS that reformat your XAML (contextual menu) and sort the atributes based on their importance (The importance in the opinion of the plugin developer.

Anyway, I'm using this plugin right now and I recomend it.

http://xamlstyler.codeplex.com/

I know this is not exactly what you want, but maybe It's a good partial solution.

Answer (score 1):

in the xaml, the order of the properties does not matter.  the visual editor will generate them in the order in which it was coded to generate them.  you can reorder them and remove the ones you want (default values will be used, if necessary), for the most part, to your hearts desire.

in  your example (for example) you don't need `Grid.Row` or `Grid.Column` if your label is not a child of a `Grid` control.   You can leave off the `Height` if you want to use the default `Height`.  Really, the only thing you SHOULD probably set is the Content--but even that is optional.

now, the other thing you can do is add a `<style>` to your resources section. by using a `<style>` you can set all of the "defaults" to what you want.  for example, you can set the background or text color to be the same on every `<Label>` or only on the ones you tell to use the style that you create.

[here](http://en.csharp-online.net/WPF_Styles_and_Control_Templates) is a pretty decent article on styles and control templates.

Comment: Lol, I guess that's not his problem. He want something like a change in the default template for a control where the properties are placed in the order that he likes, not the default order given by the current template.. :)

Comment: <sigh> It's not clear to me that that is what he is asking. I guess its a matter of someone new not knowing the terminology.